# How can i manipulate this data to be acceptable with UI - React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an appointments should be rendered based on morning/evening time.
So before back-end guy make the API I mock it in this way

```
const Data = {
  day: 'Wed 22-5-2020',
  appointments: [
    {
      name: 'morning time',
      sets: 5,
      dates: [
        '8-9 am',
        '9-10 am',
        '10-11 am',
        '11-12 am'],
    },
    {
      name: 'evening time',
      sets: 5,
      dates: [
        '12-01 pm',
        '01-02 pm',
        '02-03 pm',
        '03-04 pm',
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

and this is the result of [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fihR7.png)

But after back-end guy make an API I got the response like this

```
const Data = {
  appointments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      day: 'Saturday',
      dates_morning: [
        {
          id: 10,
          time: '10 - 10:30 am',
          type: 'morning',
          name: 'morning time',
        },
      ],
      dates_evening: [
        {
          id: 13,
          time: '3 - 4 pm',
          type: 'evening',
          name: 'evening time',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

But in this way, I can't handle it to be acceptable like UI with Animation,
And another thing I have a repeated code!!

So How can I handle this code to be like the first way with his response?

Here's a code [snippet](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/times-ui-animation)
check the comments please to understand what I mean

Comment: Ciao, so you are trying to find a way to transform back-end data like `Data` shape correct?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes, Without repeat the code as you see in the live code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I think you can try to transform data by following this example:

```js
const Data_ko = {
  appointments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      day: 'Saturday',
      dates_morning: [
        {
          id: 10,
          time: '10 - 10:30 am',
          type: 'morning',
          name: 'morning time',
        },
      ],
      dates_evening: [
        {
          id: 13,
          time: '3 - 4 pm',
          type: 'evening',
          name: 'evening time',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const result = {};
result.day = Data_ko.appointments[0].day; // here it's difficult to translate Saturday into date!
result.appointments = [];
const morning_appointment = {};
morning_appointment.name = 'morning time';
// here I don't know what does it mean sets
morning_appointment.dates = [];
morning_appointment.dates = Data_ko.appointments[0].dates_morning.map(el => {
   return el.time;
});
const evening_appointment = {};
evening_appointment.name = 'evening time';
// here I don't know what does it mean sets
evening_appointment.dates = [];
evening_appointment.dates = Data_ko.appointments[0].dates_evening.map(el => {
   return el.time;
});
result.appointments.push(morning_appointment);
result.appointments.push(evening_appointment);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: UHHH, You are right!! I don't think on this way, it's a very neat solution I forget to think about it :"D

Comment: Yeah, it's the faster way to adapt your data shape to back-end data shape.

Comment: But in this way maybe I have a delay after getting the data and manipulate it 'less Performance'?

Comment: Yes for sure you will have an additional delay (compared to not manipulate data at all). I don't know how many data you receive but you could measure. If data are not so much, delay will be irrelevant.

Comment: Hmm I think it not so much data i will receive, it's just 24hrs divide for morning/evening appointment. anyway Thank you Giovanni

Comment: So max 24 entries per day. Totally irrelevant. And with this simple transformation you avoid to have 2 different codes to manage and you will have data always in the same shape.